# Database downloaded as an .sql file - how to best access it?

Tags: java, sql, database

What's the best way to visualise it in a table form? How to later on access it from within Java code?

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking.

Comment: Step 1 - make sure you have the necessary software installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The extension of the file is not relevant here. Open the file you have downloaded and check whether it has relevant SQL. More likely, the file that you have downloaded would have DDL statements like 'create table'.

If the database you are using is MySQL, then you can use GUI based tools like WAMP, which would give an option to import the database file.

If you want to use command line in MySQL, use mysql -u root -p  < file.sql

> Regarding accessing the database from Java. You can use JDBC for that.
>
> 1) Depending on the database you are using, first download the
>   appropriate Driver jar file.
>
> 2) Use JDBC classes (DriverManager, Statement, PreparedStatement etc)
>   to do any relevant database DDL/DML operatiions.

Answer (score 0):

A .SQL file is usually a text file containing SQL queries. From Java you can access it like any other text file.

However if what you want to do is use the queries on it from your Java code I suggest either creating stored procedures on the database with that code and calling them from your code, inlining the queries in your code (as constant strings and properly parametrised) or depending on what queries are maybe you would prefer to use a ORM like Hibernate to do the same in a more Javawise way.

Comment: *A .SQL file is usually a text file containing SQL queries* I can create a file called foo.sql and fill it with random text. Looks like you haven't worked with *nix systems. Anyway, if assuming OP's file is a proper file with an extension sql and it contains proper queries, then just use `Statement` and execute each query inside it. This question leads to many interpretations, so be careful when trying to answer w/o a proper explanation of the real problem to solve.

Comment: Thats way I said "usually". If the extension wasn't important here maybe it shouldn't be on the title of the question.

Comment: The extension is irrelevant at all. The relevant element to solve the problem is knowing the contents of the file.